# Keep getting an error for join()

Tags: python

I just started learning python, and I am just trying to use the join function to combine a list to a string, but I keep getting this error

```
store_str = (',').join(store_hours)
  TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
```

Here is my code

```
time = 15

store_open = None
store_hours = [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
store_str = (',').join(store_hours)
```

Answer (score 4):

The exception is raised since integers are sent to the function instead of strings:

```
store_hours = [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
store_str = ','.join(map(str, store_hours))
```

In order to make call `str.join` the arguments need to be converted to strings first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I now understand it